# How to do form validation first and then a confirmation popup call in wicket

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket-1.5

I am using ajax button and overridding the IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator for javascript confirmation popup . when i click on button it calls this confirmation popup first then it does the form validation

Do we have any way to first do the validation and then confirmation popup to save action ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to validate after those input fields have been changed.
 So this means you could add jQuery and simply do this for example:

```
$('input#name').change(function(){
   //validate the name and display error messages
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with the code it'd be simpler to catch the issue
general recommendations: try to use  async: false in ajax call;
form validation -  inside ajax function call, show popup - outside that ajax function. Your popup probably will show different messages depending whether validation came through or not (your ajax function has some kind of validation status return)